# objective-c NSArray online testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm new to Objective-c, and trying to learn the basics of the language before I jump into iOS development. It seems like Xcode requires a more complete understanding of the whole iOS development system, so I tried to do just a simple code testing using http://www.compileonline.com/compile_objective-c_online.php this website.

I am not sure what i am missing here, but I just can't test this simple dictionary code (from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_arrays.htm).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   NSLog (@"hello world");
   [pool drain];

   NSDictionary *inventory = @{
      @"Mercedes-Benz SLK250" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:13],
      @"Mercedes-Benz E350" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:22],
   };
   // Values and keys as arguments
   inventory = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:13], @"Mercedes-Benz SLK250",
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:22], @"Mercedes-Benz E350", nil];
   // Values and keys as arrays
   NSArray *models = @[@"Mercedes-Benz SLK250", @"Mercedes-Benz E350"];
   NSArray *stock = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:13],
                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:22]];
   inventory = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:stock forKeys:models];
   NSLog(@"%@", inventory);


   return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Any question involved here at all?

Comment: The question (as I understand it) is: Why does this code not compile at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_objective-c_online.php?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the newer Objective-C features are only available with the Clang compiler
(which is used by Xcode),
but not with gcc (used by that online compiler). For example the ["Objective-C Literals"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

```
// NSDictionary literal @{ ... }
NSDictionary *inventory = @{
    @"Mercedes-Benz SLK250" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:13],
    @"Mercedes-Benz E350" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:22],
};

// NSArray literal @[ ... ]
NSArray *models = @[@"Mercedes-Benz SLK250", @"Mercedes-Benz E350"];
```

are not understood by gcc.

If you restrict your code to the "old-style" syntax

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *inventory = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:13], @"Mercedes-Benz SLK250",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:22], @"Mercedes-Benz E350", nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", inventory);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

then it will compile and run as expected on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_objective-c_online.php.

But note that gcc does not support many of the newer Objective-C features, most notably
[ARC (automatic reference counting)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/objectivec/rn-transitioningtoarc/introduction/introduction.html). So if you want to learn the language, Xcode is
currently the best development environment.

Comment: Further, you can just use the "Command Line Tool" using Foundation template in Xcode to get a project with similar structure to the above sample.